# How to deal with training data after cross validation?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, unbalanced-classes

I have imbalanced data and used undersampling to construct several logistic regression models, using the way very similar to [EasyEnsemble](https://cs.nju.edu.cn/zhouzh/zhouzh.files/publication/tsmcb09.pdf). The parameters, like regularization, number of models were tuned using cross validation. I used [sklearn's logistic regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) and `predict_proba` to obtain the posterior probabilities. The final output for each unseen sample was the average probabilities from those models. I have two questions:

1. In the case that I don't want to waste any data, I want to predict training data as well. What should I do?
2. If I still want to use posterior probabilities, how can I concatenate probabilities from training and unseen data for final decision? If I was right, I think the probabilities for training and unseen data were from different models.